# iphone - Extracting ZIP files in iPhone App

Tags: iphone, frameworks, zip

I am aware of some third party libraries and open source libraries to extract ZIP files within iPhone application.
But I would like to know whether there are any default iPhone frameworks provided in SDK itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None that I know of. I have been using [Objective-Zip](http://code.google.com/p/objective-zip/) and it seems pretty good for my needs. But I am deflating not inflating.